# How to change all of my git repos' remote addresses?

Tags: git, github, version-control, filesystems, git-config

Is there a way I can efficiently change a given remote url for a lot of (differently located) local git repositories?

**Use case 1**

I changed my username on Github.

**Use case 2**

I changed/want to change my remote git-hosting server url.

*Caveats*

 
- The repos don't consistently use the same name for the remote (so I can't just hammer through changing `origin`).

Comment: Regarding the **caveat**: Can you reliably identify the remote url you want to change? In this case you could use `git remote -vv` to get the name of the remote

Comment: Yes, I could. I could go through sed/awk/grepping the `git remote -v`'s of the world to search for the url and run `git remote set-url $1 $thechange`, but I'd rather avoid programatically walking through my global directories and adjusting remote urls if I can help it.

Comment: It would be a very unix way of doing it (chaining together a lot of small programs) and I don't see another way of doing it. If you don't want to use this approach I think I am unable to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, having not heard/found any other sneakier ways of accomplishing this, I thought I'd give a shot at a 'unixy' solve.

Look for matching path in a given parent (or grandparent...) directory, and then execute `$2` on each path/file it finds.

```
find_git_configs() {
    find $1 -path "*/.git/config" -exec $2 {} \;
}
```

Then, in action...

`find_git_configs some/where "sed -i.bak s/:3000//g"`.